# panic kernel when my laptop is being connected to a wifi network

Tags: 16.04

My laptop has a rtl8723be wifi card. The trouble started when I tried to install the latest drivers wifi version.So, The spotted problem is that when my my laptop is being connected to a wifi network, a process(named systemd-journal) automatically starts running in the background creating huge log files like 60 GB. But,when I run (sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be) both the wifi and the process turn off. I found the created files and deleted them but the question is, what can I do in order to use wifi without kernel panic. Currently I have turn off the wifi and I am using ethernet.

Comment: It was through repositories. I am writing the commands below. 
`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi`
`$ sudo apt-get update`
`$ sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware `
`$ sudo reboot`
`$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) gcc g++ build-essential dkms git`
`$ cd rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex`
`$ make`
 `$ sudo make install`
 `$ sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be `
` $ sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2` 
 `$ echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2 fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

Comment: <Exactly as you described. This is just a small sample of the created log file. / Mar 17 09:21:18 nik-HP-Pavilion-Notebook kernel: [  306.472757] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3:   device [8086:9d1b] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Mar 17 09:21:18 nik-HP-Pavilion-Notebook kernel: [  306.472775] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Mar 17 09:21:18 nik-HP-Pavilion-Notebook kernel: [  306.472789] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: AER: Corrected error received: id=00eb
Mar 17 09:21:18 nik-HP-Pavilion-Notebook kernel: [  306.473451] pcieport 0000:00:1d.3: can't find device of ID00eb>

Comment: After running the command **psi=nomsi** , the process seems to get narrowed down a little bit. Previously, it was occupying 40%-50% of CPU and now  15%-25% of CPU.  If I run **sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be**  obviously my WIFI turns off and the process stops running. But I don't have wifi then.

Comment: Mar 16 13:16:55 nik-HP-Pavilion-Notebook kernel: [    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x42/0x50d with crng_init=0
Mar 16 13:16:55 nik-HP-Pavilion-Notebook kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.13.0-37-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-012) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)) #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 16:03:28 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 4.13.0-37.42~16.04.1-generic 4.13.13)
Mar 16 13:16:55 nik-HP-Pavilion-Notebook kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=2c373ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

Comment: Is there any way to delete the wifi drivers and reinstall everything from scratch? 4 log files are being created name syslog,syslog1,kern.log,kern.log1 containing full of trash.

Comment: Also, when I run **sudo apt-get update** . I get **Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/ideapad-laptop/ubuntu xenial Release**